# my javascript script file is not being used when I preload it

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a javascript file to load another Html file (this file holds my navbar) into my main index page. I was able to do this using the Jquery code below

```
$('#sideNav').load("navbar.html");
```

This worked for loading my navbar however it gives this weird effect where the page loads and then 1 sec later the navbar loads. So I decided to try using a link tag to preload the script. I have this code below to do this

```
<link rel="preload" href="js/script.js" as="script">
```

However, using this method the navbar never loads and I receive this warning in my console

"The resource http://localhost:8080/template/js/script.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

My main question is how can I properly get the script file to preload so the navbar will be displayed at the same time as the rest of the site? If there is no way for me to do this, then how can I load my navbar and my page simultaneously even thought the navbar is being loaded using a JS script?

Thank you!

So I know I can easily use Php's include or require to complete this task however I want to do this in Javascript so I don't have to change all my files that use navbars into php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `<script src="js/script.js">` tag before `<body>` tag?

Comment: I did not do that before, However, after trying that, it still does not solve the problem.